# How to identify if a modifier is misplaced in a sentence?

Tags: dangling-modifiers

Is **"Unifying the master brand"** in the following sentence a misplaced modifier?

> Unifying the master brand, each icon also functions as a workhorse.

Comment: The question to ask is whether each icon is unifying the brand. Maybe all the icons do that, not each one.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you, that's helpful. Will the following sentence make more sense? 
"Unifying the master brand, **the icon set** also functions as a workhorse."

Comment: Sounds better to me.

Comment: There's a snag inherent to modifying ing-clauses in that they can have all sorts of attached implications. Adding 'as well as', 'as a result of', 'after' etc often disambiguates.

Comment: I’d probably add a ‘While’ to the beginning.  “While unifying the master brand, the icons also...”